# Retrieve URL from Files for PDFView

Tags: swiftui

On one of my Swift view I use .fileImporter in order to get any PDF document URL, and save it for later reference:

```
.fileImporter(isPresented: $isShowingFilePicker, allowedContentTypes: [.pdf]) { result in
  switch result {
  case .success(let url):
    let gotAccess = url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
    if !gotAccess { return }

    scoreFileLink = url.path // <- Here
                
    url.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
  case .failure(let error):
      print(error)
    }
  }
```

I'm trying to display this PDF later passing this "scoreFileLink" (which has the syntax file:///private/var/mobile/Library/...) to this PDFKitView, but it can't find file, or URL is incorrect.

```
struct PDFKitView: UIViewRepresentable {
  let urlString: String // <- Passed here
  
  func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<PDFKitView>) ->  PDFView {
    let pdfView = PDFView()

    //Checking if file exists. Always fails.
    if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: urlString) {
      print("No file found at \(urlString)")
    }

    let path = URL(fileURLWithPath: urlString)
    if let document = PDFDocument(url: path) {
      pdfView.document = document // <- No document is shown.
    }
    
    pdfView.displayMode = .singlePageContinuous
    pdfView.autoScales = true
    pdfView.displayDirection = .horizontal
    return pdfView
  }
  
  func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) { }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is about saving URL reference or getting it later for PDFView?

---

Updated with @jndpx response below about SecurityScope for retrieving url. But still doesn't work:

```
struct PDFKitView: UIViewRepresentable {
  let urlString: String
  
  func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<PDFKitView>) ->  PDFView {
    let pdfView = PDFView()
    let path = URL(fileURLWithPath: urlString)
    let accessGranted = path.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
    if accessGranted {
      
      //Checking if file exists. Always fails.
      if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: urlString) {
        print("No file found at \(urlString)")
      }

      if let document = PDFDocument(url: path) {
        pdfView.document = document
      }
      
      pdfView.displayMode = .singlePageContinuous
      pdfView.autoScales = true
      pdfView.displayDirection = .horizontal
      return pdfView
    } else {
      print("Failed to obtain access to the security-scoped resource.")
      return PDFView()
    }
  }
  
  func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) { }
}
```

---

Updated:

The strange thing is that when I save url, file is found here:

```
scoreFileLink = url.path

if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: scoreFileLink) {
   print("No file found at \(scoreFileLink)")
} else {
   print("File link is: \(scoreFileLink)")
}
```

but not when retrieved, with the same checking, on another view: scoreFileLink is the same String, but it seems document has dissapered.

Comment: You need to call `startAccessingSecurityScopedResource` when you actually access the file -- not just get the URL

Comment: I've tried, but I can't find the syntax to make it work. If I write "urlString.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()" I get the error "Value of type 'String' has no member 'startAccessingSecurityScopedResource"

Comment: Yes, you'd have to call it on the URL -- not the `path` that you're currently storing. However, you may want to copy the file to your app's own temporary storage and access it from there.

Comment: I'd prefer to keep it on original place not to "duplicate". Still not working: edited post.

Comment: I don't think there's any guarantees that `PDFDocument` only accesses the file at the exact time you create the instance. I'd suggest _trying_ the copy and seeing if that solves it. Then you'd at least know whether the problem was related to access.  Good luck

Comment: Aja, now I understand. I'll try copying to temporary and come back to inform. Thanks!

Comment: You are correct, @jnpdx: I've tried to copy to my app cache directory, and received a message saying that "I have no access to the file". But even using startAccessingSecurityScopedResource(). So what more can be done 

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved it the way @jnpdx suggested: making a copy, when importing, to iCloud app folder, and retrieving URL from there later:

```
if let iCloudContainerURL = FileManager.default.url(forUbiquityContainerIdentifier: nil)?.appendingPathComponent("Documents") {
   if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: iCloudContainerURL.path, isDirectory: nil) {
     do {
       try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: iCloudContainerURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
     } catch {
       print(error.localizedDescription)
     }
    
     let pdfFileURL = iCloudContainerURL.appendingPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent)
     if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: pdfFileURL.absoluteString) {
        do {
           try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: url, to: pdfFileURL)
           scoreFileLink = pdfFileURL.path
        } catch {
            print("Copy Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
      } else {
        print("That PDF file already exists in folder")
      }
```

Comment: Note that `error.localizedDescription` is almost always less detail (and not what you want) compared to just `error`

Comment: Yes, I know. Thanks for the observation.